# Google Maps Marker Clustering type error

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, markerclusterer

I'm attempting to convert the example WordPress Advanced Custom Fields Google Maps code to use Marker Clustering.  WordPress writes a whole load of divs to a page like this:

```
<div class="marker" data-lat="51.48956829999999" data-lng="-0.07924179999997705">
```

These are then rendered into a map as below.

```
jQuery('.acf-map').each(function(){
    render_cluster_map( jQuery(this) );
});

function render_cluster_map( $el ) {
    var $markers = $el.find('.marker');

    var args = {
        zoom        : 20,
        center      : new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
        mapTypeId   : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map( $el[0], args);
    var mc_markers = [];

    $markers.each(function(){
        var marker = jQuery(this);
        console.log('marker: '+marker)
        var latlon = new google.maps.LatLng( marker.attr('data-lat'), marker.attr('data-lng') );
        console.log('latlon: '+latlon);
        mc_markers.push( marker );
    });
    console.log('mc_markers: '+mc_markers);
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, mc_markers);
}
```

Everything appears to work fine until the final line where it tries to render the map at which point I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

My console.log outputs look like this:

```
marker: [object Object] 
latlon: (52.4602277, 0.30479379999997036) 
marker: [object Object] 
latlon: (52.226946, 0.1440727000000379) 
marker: [object Object] 
latlon: (52.45853469999999, 0.3039631000000327) 
mc_markers:
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function markerclusterer.js?ver=4.1.1:649
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function markerclusterer.js?ver=4.1.1:649
```

Can anyone shed some light on what needs to be done to sort this out?

Comment: Where did you get the MarkerClusterer and which version are you using?  This error looks strange: 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function markerclusterer.js?ver=4.1.1:649'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Maps MarkerClusterer Not Clustering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25234976/google-maps-markerclusterer-not-clustering).  You are not adding an array of  `google.maps.Marker` objects to the MarkerClusterer (mc_markers is some kind of JQuery array).

Comment: Actually this was me being an idiot.  Although I define latlon, I never actually use it.  My updated function is in the answers below

Comment: I think the reason the error looks strange is because it is added by WordPress using the enqueue_scripts function.  But it came from github

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I defined latlon, but didn't actually use it.  This worked:

```
function render_cluster_map( $el ) {
    var $markers = $el.find('.marker');
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(0,0);
    var args = {
        zoom        : 2,
        center: center,
        mapTypeId   : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map( $el[0], args);
    var mc_markers = [];

    $markers.each(function(){
        var marker = jQuery(this);
        var latlon = new google.maps.LatLng( marker.attr('data-lat'), marker.attr('data-lng') );
        var mc_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position    : latlon
        }); 
        mc_markers.push( mc_marker );
    });
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, mc_markers);
    center_map(map);
}
```